# Spring Boot @Autowired null in extends Configurator

Tags: java, spring-boot

OK. I know this question have been asked many times here but I am sorry for asking again because none of them worked for me .What I am trying to do is @Autowired my JpaRepository in a Configurator extended class here is my code for doing this but I am getting null for connections .I have searched the internet I have found that this is out of scope for spring boot and I need to inject my webSocketConfigurator class into Spring boot ? correct me If I am wrong ? if yes how can I do this

```
@Configurable
public class webSocketConfigurator extends Configurator
{
    @Autowired
    ClientConnectionDao connections;

    @Override
    public void modifyHandshake(ServerEndpointConfig config, HandshakeRequest request, HandshakeResponse response)
    {
        super.modifyHandshake(config, request, response);

        config.getUserProperties().put("ClientSession", request.getHttpSession());
    }
 }


public interface ClientConnectionDao extends JpaRepository<ClientConnection, Long> {
    public ClientConnection findByport(String port);
  public List<ClientConnection> findBymyuserName(String myUserName);


}
```

Comment: At first provide how did you define ClientConnectionDao? How is spring initializing beans in your app, is it configured in xml, programmatically or scan for annotations?  Do you use AspectJ in your application? Is ClientConnectionDao interface or concrete implementation?

Comment: @eg04lt3r added my ClientConnectionDao  in question

Comment: What about another questions?

Answer (score 2):

The correct annotation is `@Configuration`, not `@Configurable`